# playframework 2.0 render json from controller to view cause java.lang.StackOverflowError

Tags: json, jqgrid, playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.1

i m very new to play and started using play 2.0.

trying to have jqgrid in view but not able to display data, below is the code :

controller :

```
public static Result userLogs(String criteria) throws JSONException {
    JSONObject responcedata = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray logData = UserLogs.getUserlogs();
    responcedata.put("page", 1);
    responcedata.put("records", 10);
    responcedata.put("rows", logData);
    response().setContentType("application/json");
    return ok(userlogs.render(responcedata));    
}
```

model class :

public static JSONArray getUserlogs() {

```
    String query = "select date from user where user_id=1 and resp=1";
    List<SqlRow> userLogs = Ebean.createSqlQuery(query).findList();
    JSONArray cellarray = new JSONArray();
    int tableSize = userLogs.size();
    int i = 0;
    while (i < tableSize) {
        JSONObject cellObj = new JSONObject();
        JSONArray cell = new JSONArray();

        cell.put(i + 1);
        cell.put(userLogs.get(i).getTimestamp("date"));
        try {
            cellObj.put("cell", cell);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        cellarray.put(cellObj);
        i++;
    }
    return cellarray;
}
```

view :

jQuery("#grid").jqGrid({

```
    url:"@Application.userLogs(),
    datatype : 'json',
    colNames:['S.No','date'],
    colModel:[
        {name:'sno',index:'sno', width:50, sorttype:"int"},
        {name:'date',index:'date', width:150, sorttype:"date"}
              ],    
      jsonReader : {                   
        root: "rows",  
        page: "page", 
        total: "total", 
        records: "records",                   
        cell: "cell", 
        loadOnce: "true",
        id: "id",
        userdata: "userdata"
      },
      width: 900,  
      height: 220,
      rowNum:10, rowList:[10,20,30],   
      pager: '#pager',
      sortname: 'id',
      viewrecords: true,  
      gridview: true,
      sortorder: "desc",  
      loadonce:true,
      ignoreCase:true,
      multiselect: true,
         });
});
```

and below is the exception ::

play.api.Application$$anon$1: Execution exception[[RuntimeException: java.lang.StackOverflowError]]
        at play.api.Application$class.handleError(Application.scala:289) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.1]
        at play.api.DefaultApplication.handleError(Application.scala:383) [play_2.10.jar:2.1.1]
        at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anon$2$$anonfun$handle$1.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:144) [play_2.10.jar:2.1.1]
        at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anon$2$$anonfun$handle$1.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:140) [play_2.10.jar:2.1.1]
        at play.api.libs.concurrent.PlayPromise$$anonfun$extend1$1.apply(Promise.scala:113) [play_2.10.jar:2.1.1]
        at play.api.libs.concurrent.PlayPromise$$anonfun$extend1$1.apply(Promise.scala:113) [play_2.10.jar:2.1.1]
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.StackOverflowError
        at play.libs.F$Promise$6.apply(F.java:401) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.1]
        at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$map$1.liftedTree2$1(Future.scala:253) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
        at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Future.scala:249) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
        at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Future.scala:249) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
        at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:29) ~[scala-library.jar:na]
        at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.liftedTree1$1(BatchingExecutor.scala:67) ~[akka-actor_2.10.jar:na]
java.lang.StackOverflowError: null
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:431) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.18.jar:na]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.getInstance(PreparedStatement.java:872) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.18.jar:na]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.clientPrepareStatement(ConnectionImpl.java:1490) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.18.jar:na]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.prepareStatement(ConnectionImpl.java:4253) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.18.jar:na]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.prepareStatement(ConnectionImpl.java:4152) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.18.jar:na]
        at com.jolbox.bonecp.ConnectionHandle.prepareStatement(ConnectionHandle.java:820) ~[bonecp.jar:0.7.1.RELEASE]

pls let me know how to handle this scenario and display the list in view using jqgrid.
any alternate ways to achieve this also helps.

thanks..!!!

Comment: The problem is maybe in `UserLogs.getUserlogs()`, please show the code.

Comment: hi nico, i hav edited the question wid the above method asked..thanks for ur response.